# Converting Observable to array angular 4 HTTP

Tags: angular, http, typescript, angular4-httpclient

I have a service which is fetching a list of books locally I get this error:

```
BooksComponent.html:2 ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object 
'[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
    at NgForOf.webpackJsonp.../../../common/@angular/common.es5.js.NgForOf.ngOnChanges (common.es5.js:1681)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (
```

This is my service Class:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Books } from './books';

@Injectable()
export class FetchbooksService {
books:any[];
  constructor(private _http:Http) { }
  fetch():Observable<Books[]>{
    return this._http.get('./assets/books.json').map(
      (response:Response)=> <Books[]>response.json(),
      error => console.log(error)
    ).do(data => console.log(data));
  }
}
```

and this is the component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core'; 
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { FetchbooksService }  from  '../fetchbooks.service';
import { Books } from '../books';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-books',
  templateUrl: './books.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./books.component.css']
})
export class BooksComponent implements OnInit {
 bookss:Books[];
   constructor(private _bookservice: FetchbooksService) {
    _bookservice.fetch().subscribe(
     (bookss)=> this.bookss = bookss,
      error => console.log(error)=
    );

   }

   ngOnInit() {
 }

}
```

Books is an interface
please tell me what  am I doing wrong?

this is books.component.html :

```
 <ul>
  <li *ngFor = "let book of bookss ">
    Book: {{book.title}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

and this is the data returned by the service :
[console.log(bookss) result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKPEh.png)

Comment: This error is not in `TS` side, its a HTML iteration error. Could you post the `BooksComponent.html` file please. The error is in `*ngFor` of that file.

Comment: If we could also see the `console.log` of your data that's getting retrieved from the service, that would be great. Is there a chance that, even though you're expecting an array of Books (`Books[]`), you're receiving some other data structure?

Comment: thanks for the reply I have added the html and console.log in the question please look at it and tell me whats wrong with it thank alot

Comment: I think as you see from console the books is an object not an array, I think it should be an array so ngfor can loop over it

Comment: how can I can convert it to array?? and where should I do that in the service or the component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned, you are not receiving an array, but an object with nested objects. You need to either use a custom pipe, or then transform the data in the component.

If you want to go with the custom pipe... This is the way to go, **if you need to maintain the key!**.. which I image you need in this case.

import necessary stuff:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({ name: 'keys' }) 
export class ValuesPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: any, args?: any[]): any[] {
        let keyArr: any[] = Object.keys(value),
            dataArr = [];
        keyArr.forEach((key: any) => {
            dataArr.push(value[key]);
        });
        return dataArr;
    }
}
```

add the `ValuesPipe` to your `declarations` array in your module, and use it like the following in the template:

```
<div *ngFor="let book of bookss | keys">
  {{book.author }} : {{ book.title }}
</div>
```

Just for future tip, remember, if you go with the pipe, remember if it needs to be `impure` the pipe is very costly and fired often.

---

If the build of the data doesn't need to stay the same as it was when received. So after receiving the data I would call a method that makes your data iterable, **BUT, here you loose the key** (needs some modification to keep the key)

```
_bookservice.fetch().subscribe(
 (bookss) => {
    this.bookss = bookss.books;
    this.transform();
 },
  error => console.log(error)
);

transform(books) {
  let keyArr: any[] = Object.keys(books),
    dataArr = [];
    keyArr.forEach((key: any) => {
      dataArr.push(books[key]);
    });
  return dataArr;
}
```

Comment: PS, this very much probably a duplicate, but I couldn't find one when searching, which would apply with this specific set of how data is built.